# Why this url search does not work - url:*doi.org/10.1007/BF02684339*? How to modify it to find what I am looking for?

Tags: support, search, hyperlinks

The following two posts both contain the [link](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02684339) `https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02684339`
[quasi-finite group schemes](https://mathoverflow.net/q/286796) ([revisions](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/286796/revisions), [source](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/ad5a08ab-23fc-4ea5-9f02-7883c3f33a05/view-source)) and [Criterion for constancy in Mazur's Eisenstein ideal paper](https://mathoverflow.net/q/285462) ([revisions](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/285462/revisions), [source](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/68ad5a1d-8672-4a2f-874e-1cc62107b067/view-source)).

However, when I try to search for [url:https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02684339](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fdoi.org%2F10.1007%2FBF02684339) or [url:doi.org/10.1007/BF02684339](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3Adoi.org%2F10.1007%2FBF02684339). I have tried also some reasonably looking modifications with wildcards: [`url:*doi.org/10.1007/BF02684339*`](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3A*doi.org%2F10.1007%2FBF02684339*), [`url:*10.1007/BF02684339*`](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3A*10.1007%2FBF02684339*) or [`url:*BF02684339*`](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3A*BF02684339*). What can I do so that I get among search results these two posts. (And maybe also other posts which might contain the same url.)

---

Some additional remarks. If I simply [search for BF02684339](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=BF02684339), one of those two posts is among results.

The kind of links I mentioned is link based on [Digital Object Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier). These links are supposed to be permanent and id should identify the paper uniquely. This is a reason why somebody citing the paper could simply include only DOI and rely on the fact that from DOI readers of the post can get all necessary bibliographic information about the paper.

So I can imagine that somebody might include DOI link without explicitly writing the names of the authors and the title of the paper. In the case of these two specific posts, both of them are found if I [search for author and part of the title](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=Mazur+modular+eisenstein). Still, if there are some posts only including DOI-based link, it would be nice to have possibility to find them.

**EDIT: Based on Glorfindel's answer, the problem seems to be simply that I should have included "..." around the url. It seems that all searches mentioned above are working after this modification:

- [url:"https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02684339"](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3A"https%3A%2F%2Fdoi.org%2F10.1007%2FBF02684339")
- [url:"doi.org/10.1007/BF02684339"](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3A"doi.org%2F10.1007%2FBF02684339")
- [`url:"*doi.org/10.1007/BF02684339*"`](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3A"*doi.org%2F10.1007%2FBF02684339*")
- [`url:"*10.1007/BF02684339*"`](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3A"*10.1007%2FBF02684339*")
- [`url:"*BF02684339*"`](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3A"*BF02684339*")

I suppose my confusion was caused by the fact that searches sometimes work without quotation marks: for example: 
[`url:*doi*`](https://mathoverflow.net/search?tab=active&q=url%3a*doi*),
[`url:*proxy*`](https://mathoverflow.net/search?tab=active&q=url%3a*proxy*), 
[`url:*imgur*`](https://mathoverflow.net/search?tab=active&q=url%3a*imgur*) or 
[`url:*png*`](https://mathoverflow.net/search?tab=active&q=url%3a*png*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in the advanced search tips, you need to enclose the URL in double quotes.

[image]

Using `url:"doi.org/10.1007/BF02684339"` seems to work ([direct link](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3A%22doi.org%2F10.1007%2FBF02684339%22)).

Comment: [D'oh!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27oh!) I should have noticed it myself. Anyway, I have tested all other searches with addition of quotation marks (see my edit) and all of them. (See the edit to the question.) Thanks a lot!